# Debugging Triggered events in Webkit Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have various JS files included in an HTML page and am trying to debug when an event is being triggered.  There is an issue in this app I'm helping out on where when the user presses the left or right arrows then the mousemove event is being triggered.  In Chrome, I'm using the Developer Tools and am trying to find where this mousemove event is being triggered. In the Scripts tab of the Developer Tools, I have Event Listener breakpoints set for keyup and mousemove.  When the page hits the breakpoints, both call stacks show jquery.js.  How do I pinpoint and debug which element is triggering these events?  I'd like to find a way to have the Developer Tools give me a line number of a file other than jquery.js.

Also, this issue only appears in Chrome for some reason.

Comment: Visual Event, http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event . I am sure that that will help half of the people landing on this stackoverflow page :)